# Outlook preventing Windows from shutting down

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook-2013

I use Outlook 2013 on a Windows 7 (64 bit) pc.

Whenever I try to shut down / restart my pc I see that windows 7 waits applications to close, when I press cancel I see an Outlook form:

[image]

Is there any way to prevent Outlook delaying shut down? Or set it to always permanently empty "Deleted items" folder without asking?

Comment: There are separate options, noted in the linked question: One choosing to empty Deleted Items on Exit, the other controlling whether there is a confirmation prompt when emptying the deleted items.

Answer (score 7):

This option is available inside the settings.

Go to File -> Options -> Advanced.

Here you'll see a section called "Outlook start and exit" and one of the options in here is a checkbox for emptying the deleted items folder when exiting Outlook.

Untick this and you should be in the clear.

Comment: Good answer, @Stephen, otherwise the OP would have to close Outlook first to say "Yes" or "No" that that prompt if he/she would like to keep this function enabled, then shut down the computer.

Comment: @RMarkwald Thanks.  The only thing I will say is I have this option set and I don't get asked.

Comment: This basically stops outlook from clearing the deleted items, meaning that the user has to manually clean the deleted items themselves. Given that this option is disabled by default, what makes you think the user wants to stop using this? Also, I think there's a fundamental difference in Windows 7's shutdown routine and Windows 10's shutdown routine, where Windows 10 most likely will not halt on this.